# Windows 7 video capture - says camera is in use by another application

Tags: windows-7, drivers, video-capture, tuner-card

I've got an AverMedia DVD EZMaker USB Gold (C308) video capture device. I've installed the drivers for it and Windows (7 x64) seems to recognize is OK, but I cannot view any video in any capture software. Any software says that the device may already be in use.

Is there any way to tell what software may be interfearing with the video stream? Or any other tips for getting this working?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is either a Driver conflict or a virus infection. If you have a printer or scanner, try unplugging them and then plugging the cam and then check if it gives the same error.

If it does, Scan for viruses and Uncheck all the unnecessary processes from the startup list.